# Transform a formula in vba code

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula, drag, formulas

I have this formula

```
=IF(A10='[file1.xls]Sheet1'!$D$1,'[file1.xls]Sheet1'!$F$4,0)
```

and the same formula only with 2 changes of cells

```
=IF(A11='[file1.xls]Sheet1'!$J$1,'[file1.xls]Sheet1'!$L$4,0)
```

Is there a way to drag the formula on a column or to transform it in VBA code?

Thank you

Comment: you can drag down to switch `A10` to `A11` but since `D` is not next to `J`, nor is `F` next to `L` it would be hard to drag over. That said, if you can post a screenshot sample of your data, there may be something we could offer in terms of `OFFSET` or `MATCH` or something to help with this. As it is, it's hard to work with without more context. There's also many ways to transform it with VBA, but again, context is important.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you will know the cell you are targeting for the range to be in.  So you can use those variables to build you formula in VBA

```
Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet
Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")

ws.Range("B1").Formula = "=IF(" & targetColumn & targetrow & "='[file1.xls]Sheet1'!$" & targetColumn & "$" & targetrow & ",'[file1.xls]Sheet1'!$" & targetColumn & "$" & targetrow & ",0)"
```

Answer (score 0):

Once you have manually entered your formula in a cell (e.g B10), press Ctrl+G to get to the debug window, and from there type:

```
print range("B10").formula
```

or

```
print range("B10").formulaR1C1
```

Is that what you want ?

If you want a more sophisticated solution that doubles the `"` etc, you can use [a function I wrote many years ago](http://idevlop.blogspot.lu/2009/09/generer-du-vba-avec-excel-vba.html). Unfortunalety Blogger is firewalled where I work so I can't copy the content here now.